# populate dropdown options based on another dropdown selection in mvc

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 2 drop down one (i.e) **mutualExcParam**. It has 3 options. Based on this option selected, need to populate a another drop down (i.e) **agencyRetrieve**.
This is done via JSON request and working fine for less records. If records coming more count > 500 its getting time to load. Is there any other way to do the same as performance is affecting when i **loop** through it..

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
$('.mutualExcParam').change(function () { // calling by class name on 1st dropdown
    var agencyRetrieveId = $(this).attr('id') + '_'; // 2nd dropdown id

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: "../Report/FillAgencyValue",
        data: JSON.stringify({ agencyId: agencyId}),
        success: function (data) {
            $('#' + agencyRetrieveId).html('');
            var optionhtml1 = '<option value="All">Select All</option>';
            $('#' + agencyRetrieveId).append(optionhtml1);
            $(data).each(function () {
             $('#' + agencyRetrieveId).append($("<option></option>").val(this.Value).html(this.Text));    
            });
            $(".selectpicker").selectpicker('refresh');
        }
    });
});
});

 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FillAgencyValue(int agencyId, string fromDate, string toDate, int salesArea, string[] salesGroup)
    {
        AppCode.CommonCommands commonCommands = new AppCode.CommonCommands();

        PopulateControlData populateControlData = new PopulateControlData();
        // Get all Sales Area
        DataTable dtsalesArea = commonCommands.GetAgencyDropdownData(agencyId, fromDate, toDate, salesArea, salesGroup);

        populateControlData.agencyValues = new List<SelectListItem>();
        if (dtsalesArea.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            populateControlData.agencyValues = (from DataRow row in dtsalesArea.Rows
                                                select new SelectListItem
                                                {
                                                    Text = row["ParameterLabel"].ToString(),
                                                    Value = row["ParameterValue"].ToString()
                                                }).ToList();
        }
        return Json(populateControlData.agencyValues, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: you might consider returning HTML from your `FillAgencyValue` instead.

Comment: Yes. Added controller code peace also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code to return HTML.  I have not included the `select all` option, this can be added by just doing an insert before the return in the controller method.

I have not tested the code, it is concept only.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
$('.mutualExcParam').change(function () { // calling by class name on 1st dropdown
    var agencyRetrieveId = $(this).attr('id') + '_'; // 2nd dropdown id

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: "../Report/FillAgencyValue",
        data: { agencyId: agencyId},
        success: function (data) {
            $('#' + agencyRetrieveId).empty();
            $('#' + agencyRetrieveId).html(data);
        }
    });
});
});

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FillAgencyValue(int agencyId, string fromDate, string toDate, int salesArea, string[] salesGroup)
{
    AppCode.CommonCommands commonCommands = new AppCode.CommonCommands();

    PopulateControlData populateControlData = new PopulateControlData();
    // Get all Sales Area
    DataTable dtsalesArea = commonCommands.GetAgencyDropdownData(agencyId, fromDate, toDate, salesArea, salesGroup);

    List<string> lst = new List<string>();
    if (dtsalesArea.Rows.Count > 0)
    {

        lst = (from DataRow row in dtsalesArea.Rows
               select new string.Format("<option value='{0}'>{1}</option>", row["ParameterValue"], row["ParameterLabel"])).ToList();
    }
    return Content(string.Join(lst, "\n"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea.I have tried the same.. 
If I add this  data: JSON.stringify({ agencyId: agencyId}) 
then only its hitting the controller method  FillAgencyValue.. 
Facing issues while return list from controller

Comment: its very likely that there is an error in getting to this method as there are parameters expected and not defined in your AJAX call.  For instance: `salesArea` debugging in your browser (F12) should reveal this.

Comment: When i passing like this 
data: JSON.stringify({ agencyId: agencyId, fromDate: $('#From-10').val(), toDate: $('#To-11').val(), salesArea: $('#Area_1').val() }),

i am able to get the data.. Thanks a lot it worked for me ..